# Como usar LogicException do PHP?

Tags: php, exceção

Estou estudando o tratamento de erros no PHP, e já sei como utilizar `Exception`, mas fiquei na dúvida sobre a `LogicException`, qual o propósito dela? E como utilizar de forma correta?

Answer (score 1):

[`LogicException`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.logicexception.php) de acordo com a documentação do PHP, é tipo de exceção relacionada a algum erro de lógica na sua aplicação, que irá implicar numa mudança no seu código.

Em outras palavras, seria os erros onde *"Huuum... isso não devia ter acontecido".*

**Exemplo**

Não consegui pensar em uma situação real mais elaborada, mas nesse caso a implementação está funcionando

```
<?php

Class Divisao
{
    private $divisor;
    private $dividendo;

    public function __construct($dividendo, $divisor){
        $this->dividendo = (int) $dividendo;
        $this->divisor = (int) $divisor;        
    }

    private function valida(){
        // @todo Verifica se o Divisor é Igual a 0
        return true;
    }

    public function dividir(){
        if ($this->valida()){

            // Se mesmo depois da validação o divisor for Zero, temos um erro de lógica.
            if ($this->divisor === 0) throw new LogicException('Validação Falhou');

            return $this->dividendo / $this->divisor;
        }
    }
}
try {
    $d1 = new Divisao(2,2);
    $d2 = new Divisao(2,0);

    echo $d1->dividir();
    echo $d2->dividir();

} catch (LogicException $e) {
    echo "Erro de Lógica " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: ok, como seria a implementação desta exceção? do mesmo modo que a Exception normal? já fiz isso e nenhum resultado :/

Answer (score 1):

A exceção [`LogicException`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.logicexception.php) é lançada quando o código apresenta algum erro de lógica.

> Exceção que representa erro na lógica do programa. Este tipo de
>   exceção deve levar diretamente a uma correção em seu código.

O uso de `LogicException` é semelhante ao [`DomainException`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domainexception.php), ele deve ser usado se o seu código produz um valor que não deveria produzir.

> A exceção [`DomainException`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domainexception.php) é lançada quando um valor não adere a
>   um domínio de dados válidos definidos.

Exemplo:

```
function diaUtil($dia){
    switch ($dia){
        case 2:  echo "Segunda-feira"; break;
        case 3:  echo "Terça-feira";   break;
        case 4:  echo "Quarta-feira";  break;
        case 5:  echo "Quinta-feira";  break;
        case 6:  echo "Sexta-Feira";   break;
        default:
                 throw new DomainException("Não é um dia útil válido");
    }
}

diaUtil(3);  // Terça-feira
diaUtil(10); // Não é um dia útil válido
```

<kbd>[Ver **DEMO**](http://ideone.com/6fkMcG)</kbd>

Hierarquia:

[image: inserir descrição da imagem]

1. [`LogicException`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.logicexception.php) (extensão de `Exception`)

   - [`BadFunctionCallException`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.badfunctioncallexception.php)
   - [`BadMethodCallException`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.badmethodcallexception.php)
   - [`DomainException`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domainexception.php)
   - [`InvalidArgumentException`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.invalidargumentexception.php)
   - [`LengthException`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.lengthexception.php)
   - [`OutOfRangeException`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.outofrangeexception.php)
2. [`RuntimeException`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.runtimeexception.php) (extensão de `Exception`)

   - [`OutOfBoundsException`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.outofboundsexception.php)
   - [`OverflowException`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.overflowexception.php)
   - [`RangeException`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.rangeexception.php)
   - [`UnderflowException`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.underflowexception.php)
   - [`UnexpectedValueException`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.unexpectedvalueexception.php)